# String get from CDATA, returned 0 when was converted to "int"

Tags: php, string, int, cdata

I get text include in a CDATA that looks like this in its xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://splashurl.com/nztqga8
<Document>

<name>OpenCellID Cells</name>
<description>List of available cells</description>
<Placemark><name></name><description><![CDATA[lat: <b>3.378199</b><br/>lon:      <b>-76.523528</b><br/>mcc: <b>732</b><br/>mnc: <b>123</b><br/>lac: <b>4003</b><br/>cellid: <b>26249364</b><br/>averageSignalStrength: <b>0</b><br/>samples: <b>10</b><br/>changeable: <b>1</b>]]></description><Point><coordinates>-76.523528,3.378199,0</coordinates></Point></Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

I get  the CDATA text usign the next code in PHP :

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);    // get the url contents

$data = curl_exec($ch); // execute curl request
curl_close($ch);


$xml = simplexml_load_string($data,'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA | LIBXML_NOBLANKS); // permite

foreach ($xml->Document->Placemark as $mensaje)
$resuktado[]= (string) $mensaje->description.' ';
```

How I need the lat, lon and cellid values, I get it using this:

```
$string_array = explode("<br/>",$resuktado[$i]);// separar por salto de linea el string
$latitud= explode(" ",$string_array[0]);
```

And the lattitud[1] get the lat value.

Whe I show this value in scream it looks like this: 
 **3.378199**

But whe i convert it into a int value using:

echo   (int) lattitud[1]; 
It returns 0.

How Can I convert this string an int valule that it represents

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the code is that it $latitud[1] contains the string `<b>3.378199</b>`, not just the number it self.
There are various ways to fix it. Here is one, using regular expression;

```
preg_match("/\<b\>([^\<]+)/", $latitud[1], $match);
$lat=$match[1]; // outputs 3.378199
```

---

By the way, in PHP, you usually do not need to convert between string and int.

```
$a="1";
echo $a+1;
```

Puts 2.
However if you feel that you really need to convert it, you could try

```
intval().
```

http://php.net/intval

If you just want to get rid of the decimal you could use one of theese:

```
floor();
ceil();
round();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. But when I write:  echo lattitud[1]+ 1 ; It returns 1. I dont understand why it was happening

Comment: But when you write echo lattitud[1]; you get 3.378199 ?

Comment: I found it! $lattitud[1] holds <b>3.378199</b>. So you will have to get it out of there.

Comment: I wrote a solution suggestion.